# Svg pass parameter

Tags: html, svg

I'm trying to pass parameters to the svg, but I'm not doing something wrong can you give me a hand?

Link: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/html-code-editor-forked-31jh1?file=/button.svg)

Html:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="button.svg?color=yellow">
      <param name="color" value="red" />
      <param name="label" value="stop" />
</object>
```

Svg:

```
<svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
viewBox="0 0 110 40"
width="100%"
height="100%">
    <g>
        <rect 
id="button_rect" 
x="5" 
y="5" 
width="100" 
height="30" 
rx="15" 
ry="15" 
fill="param(color) blue" 
stroke="navy"
/>
<text id="button_label" x="55" y="30" text-anchor="middle" 
            font-size="25" fill="white" font-family="Verdana"
            content-value="param(label)">
            Ok
          </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: you need to include [param.js](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGParamPrimer/param.js) per https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGParamPrimer/#:~:text=The%20SVG%20Parameters%20specification%20is,without%20the%20use%20of%20script.

Comment: I tried to include it you can see it on the codesanbox, but it's not working.

Comment: I am trying in every way, but I am not succeeding.

Answer (score 6):

The folks who have written the specs have noted that while this isn't implemented in the browser itself, you need to include a Javascript library. What they left out is **where** you should include it. Obviously your first thought might be to include it inside the html document but that's not the case - it needs to be included in the .svg file as:

```
<script type="text/ecmascript" xlink:href="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/modules/ref/master/ref2.js"></script>
```

Furthermore I'd recommend referencing the parameters using the `url(#parameterName)` syntax.

For example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="button.svg?fill=red">
      <param name="fill" value="blue" />
      <param name="stroke" value="red" />
    </object>
  </body>
</html>
```

and button.svg:

```
<svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
viewBox="0 0 110 40"
width="100%"
height="100%">
<defs>
    <ref id="paramX" param="fill" default="red"/>
    <ref id="paramY" param="stroke" default="blue"/>

</defs>
    <g>
        <rect 
id="button_rect" 
x="5" 
y="5" 
width="100" 
height="30" 
rx="15" 
ry="15" 
fill="url(#paramX)" 
stroke="url(#paramY)"
/>
<text 
id="button_label" 
x="55"
y="30"
text-anchor="middle" 
font-size="25"
fill="white"
font-family="Verdana" >
Go
</text>
    </g>
<script type="text/ecmascript" xlink:href="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/modules/ref/master/ref2.js"></script>
</svg>
```

Comment: It seems to work, but if I want to pass a text to a Text component, how can I do: https://codesandbox.io/s/html-code-editor-forked-5vv45?file=/button.svg

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and unraveling! But frankly, I'm not sure if this w3c "graveyard" concept (it was supposed to be implemented natively) provides any benefits compared to dynamically JS generated svg or something like native web components. (just a little rant against the w3c working group for leaving all the remnants of deprecated drafts in the public domain without clearly marking them as deprecated)