# How to use svg parameters?

Tags: svg, parameters

SVG allows parameters to files so a shape can use those values to draw.
I found this document describing parameters in svg:
https://dev.w3.org/SVG/modules/ref/master/SVGRefPrimer.html

However, the examples I have seen only set parameters like color to the parameter.
Also, an entire svg file must be parameterized, so while svg allows multiple definitions in a file (the defs tag) those definitions do not appear to be able to accept parameters.

It also allows defs, which are defined shapes that can be reused in a file.
But the defs are hardcoded, meaning as far as I can tell, I can only repeat the same shape at different locations.

First question: is it possible to parameterize an svg file so that the text changes?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g>
        <text x="0" y="5" class="q">param(id).</text>
        <ellipse cx="42" cy="0" rx="12" ry="10" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
        <text x="37" y="5" class="bubble">A</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

If the above file is named x.svg, then s.svg?id=1   should display 1. as text
Is this possible, and if so, is it possible to do this displayed within the defs section?

Comment: Sorry, one of those SVG spec/doc graveyards ... Better opt for a native web component.  Probably you'll find examples by @Danny '365CSI' Engelman. See also ["Svg pass parameter"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64374421/svg-pass-parameter). Seriously, those `<object>` based svg 'tricks' are kind of outdated – if you need additional JS you could as well do this in JS from the beginning (e.g dynamically creating/appending the svg or as mentioned before as a web component). So this w3c example is completely pointless and more importantly it should clearly be marked as deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every modern browser supports **Web Components**

You can use those to create SVG ***Client Side***

```html
<svg-label fill=aqua stroke=red >Hello</svg-label>
<svg-label fill=teal stroke=yellow >Web</svg-label>
<svg-label fill=orange stroke=blue >Components!</svg-label>

<script>
  customElements.define("svg-label", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      setTimeout(() => { // ensure inner DOM is parsed (callback fires on the opening tag)
        let fill   = this.attributes.fill.value;
        let stroke = this.attributes.stroke.value;
        let d      = "M0 50L50 0L100 50L50 100z";
        let text   = this.innerHTML;
        let svg    = `<svg width="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">`+
                       `<path d="${d}" fill="${fill}" stroke="${stroke}" stroke-width="15" width="100%" height="100%"/>`+
                      `<text y="50%" x="10%" fill="white" stroke="none">${text}</text>`+
                     `</svg>`
        this.innerHTML = svg;
      });
    }
  })
</script>
```

Just one easy example.

It is all HTML, CSS and JavaScript, so you can perform any DOM magic you know

My more complex answers on StackOverflow using Web Components are tagged JSWC,
So easy to find: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2520800+jswc